# Javascript, php, mysql, and json has me stumped

Tags: json

Been reading up on php and json and am trying this piece of code which is not working and I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

I call a JavaScript function from my html file onLoad(). That function is

```
    function getSched()
    {
        $.post("schedlz.php", {dat: ""+inputString+"", action: "searchSched"}, function(data)
    {
            var y="";
    if(data.length >0) 
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        y = getRes (data);
        }
        else //some error handler
}
function getRes(data)
{
    var str="";
    var obj = JSON.parse (data);
    alert (data.length + " | " +obj + " | ");
    return str;
}
```

In schedlz.php file

```
$conn = getDbConn();
mysql_select_db("myschedulez", $conn);
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        // $rows['schedulez'][] = $r;
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
 mysql_close($conn);
```

The problem is that I get the data back in correct json format but when I parse it, there is no Object. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: You have a JavaScript error in your if statement of the post.  Either remove the else entirely or put empty curly brackets after it.  Are you sure your query is getting results back?

Comment: did you copy your `getSched()` function like that on purpose, maybe to show only some part, or it's actually messed up like that?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I may have caused with my incomplete copy and past of the code. There are no JavaScript errors in my code BTW, it is my sloppiness in copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `dataType` parameter to your `$.post`, which in your case is `json`.
I'm also not sure if you closed `$.post` correctly in your sample so I'm adding the closing `);` as well.

```
function getSched()
{
    $.post("schedlz.php", 
    {dat: ""+inputString+"", action: "searchSched"}, 
    function(data) {
      var y="";
      if(data.length >0) 
      {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        y = getRes (data);
      }
      else {} //some error handler
    },
    'json'
    ); 
}
```

Comment: ace, that did the trick! I looked at the jQuery.post docs and realized that the "intelligent Guess" for the data type is not really working :)

Comment: Yes, happened to me before too, :)

Comment: Good to hear that I am not the only one ;) Any thoughts on the Unexpected character error? Thanks.